# Android Location is null

Tags: android

I want to Retrive The Location of device. i am doing it on my emulator. My emulator is Google Api's (Google inc.).I am using LocationManager class and GPS provider to get the current location but my location is always null. i gave my emulator dummy coordinates and added all the permissions in the manifest.

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (l!= null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Location is null", 300).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this,"Location is not null",300).show();
    }
}

}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.gotya"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="6"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.gotya.Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".CodeReceiver">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android SDK doc reads:

> `getLastKnownlocation` returns the last known location for the provider. If the provider is currently disabled, `null` is returned.

Also, the emulator can only emulate the GPS.

Bottom line: ensure that your program uses this location provider.